# How do I restrict connections to a service to a list of pods in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a namespace with three pods (deployments) `app01`, `app02`, and `db`. `db` is exposed within the cluster via a `ClusterIP` service with name `dbsvc`. I connect to the service from `app01` and `app02` using the cluster DNS like `dbsvc.namespace.svc.cluster.local`. However, I do not want anyone to access `dbsvc` from outside my namespace. (Since it's ClusterIP, it's not going to be accessible outside the cluster anyways).

In other words, I want to restrict access to `dbsvc.namespace.svc.cluster.local` only from `app01` and `app02`.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Network traffic can be restricted with a [Network Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) on a cluster using a [network plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/) (CNI) that supports them, like [calico](https://www.projectcalico.org/).

The policy selectors are deployment specific so here are some example values:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: app-network-policy
  namespace: namespace
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      role: db
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          project: myproject
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          role: app
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
```